# Asp.net core identity bulk insert users

Tags: asp.net-identity, ef-core-2.0, ef-bulkinsert

I am using https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions for bulk inserting data into database for better performance. Now I want to do the same while adding users in AspNetUsers table via `userManager.CreateAsync()` method, Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you got any answer regarding this or solved it on your own?

Comment: @mgsdew, haven't got any answer yet, for now, I am turning off change detection before bulk inserting users via user manager. That has improved a little speed.

Comment: how do you turn off change detection for `usermanager`?

Comment: @HamzaKhanzada you need to turn off AutoSaveChanges property of UserStore